# call more than one graphql query in one schema.graphqls file

Tags: magento2.3, related-products, graphql, mostview-product-collection

```
type Query {
    productReview: ProductReviewRatingsMetadata! @doc(description: "Retrieves metadata required by clients to render the Reviews section.") @resolver(class: "E50\\Graphql\\Model\\Resolver\\MostViewedProducts")
}

type Query {
    scandiMenu(
    identifier: String!
    ): Menu @resolver(class: "E50\\Graphql\\Model\\Resolver\\ScandiMenu") @doc(description: "Returns Scandi Menu Manager menu data")
}

type ProductReviewRatingsMetadata {
    items: [ProductReviewRatingMetadata!]! @doc(description: "List of product reviews sorted by position")
}

type ProductReviewRatingMetadata {
    id: String! @doc(description: "An encoded rating ID.")
    name: String! @doc(description: "The label assigned to an aspect of a product that is being rated, such as quality or price")
    values: [ProductReviewRatingValueMetadata!]! @doc(description: "List of product review ratings sorted by position.") @resolver(class: "Magento\\ReviewGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\ProductReviewRatingValueMetadata")
}

type ProductReviewRatingValueMetadata {
    value_id: String! @doc(description: "An encoded rating value id.")
    value: String! @doc(description: "A ratings scale, such as the number of stars awarded")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can write more than one query in schema.graphqls file:

```
type Query {
    megaMenu(
    identifier: String!
    ): Menu @resolver(class: "Vendor\\Graphql\\Model\\Resolver\\MegaMenu") @doc(description: "Returns Scandi Menu Manager menu data")
    mostReviewedProducts (
        filter: ProductAttributeFilterInput @doc(description: "Identifies which product attributes to search for and return."),
        pageSize: Int = 20 @doc(description: "Specifies the maximum number of results to return at once. This attribute is optional."),
        currentPage: Int = 1 @doc(description: "Specifies which page of results to return. The default value is 1.")
    ): Products
    @resolver(class: "Vendor\\Graphql\\Model\\Resolver\\Product") @doc(description: "")
}
```